# how to get realname from inotify with webdav

Tags: php, webdav, inotify

I have a php script witch monitors a webdav directory for new / changed files.
but when there is any action in the directory inotify only returns a temp name (.davfs.tmp251671). not the actual file name.

is there any change i can get the real file name from inotify and webdav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found A solution.
i was using IN_CREATE (and for testing IN_CLOSE) as triggers
but that gave me the above result. a temp name..
so i used IN_ALL_EVENTS for testing.
and found that mask 128 gave the realname of the file.
but...
according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/inotify.constants.php
IN_MOVED_FROM = 64
but when testing IN_CREATE gave 256
so the order in wich the are displayed on the php manual site is incorrect.
i now use the numeric value 128 for add_watch. and it works!

Comment: Had the same issue. 128 is `IN_MOVED_TO` and that's the event that gave you the real file name. Basically a temp dir is created (`IN_CREATE`), then renamed (`IS_MOVED_FROM` and `IS_MOVED_TO`, both with the same cookie). So check for the two rename events, last one gives you the real name